# How can properties.load() accept a non-inputStream

Tags: java, types, parameters

According to it's [doc page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load%28java.io.InputStream%29), java.util.Properties.load() only accepts a java.io.InputStream .  Why is it that I can safely load a [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html), when it is clearly not a child of InputStream?

This prints the properties from pFile.  It works for some reason:

```
    String pFile = "/path/to/properties/file";
    Properties p = new Properties();
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(pFile);
    p.load(fr);
    System.out.println(p.toString());
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're using a version of Java >= 1.6, which introduced Properties.load(Reader).